# Generic R2DBC Custom Converter

Tags: postgresql, generics, spring-webflux, r2dbc

I am using postgres database with reactive repository and R2dbc and have more than 5 json fields.
R2dbc does not directly recognize the jsonb fields and hence cannot map it to java object.

So after following various docs - I came to know a solution - custom converters.

So, I created converters for all fields. However, then I saw that the code in all the converters were same - just the class mapped were different (POJOs).
Hence, I thought of creating a generic class for the converters.

However, Spring is not recognizing the generic class but works with a separate converter for all the fields.

I would like to add more json fields in future and do not want to create a separate converter class for each.

Please help me with this issue.

Entity Class:

```
@Data
@Table("person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String uid;

    private AddressInfo address;

    ...
}
```

Working custom converter for one of field:

```
@ReadingConverter
@Slf4j
public class JsonToAddressInfoConverter implements Converter<Json, AddressInfo> {

    @Override
    public AddressInfo convert(Json json) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            AddressInfo addressInfo = mapper.readValue(json.asString(), AddressInfo.class);
            return addressInfo;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Problem while parsing JSON: {}", json, e);
        }
        return new AddressInfo();
    }
}
```

Generic converter that I am trying to create - (not working)

```
@ReadingConverter
@Slf4j
public class JsonToSimplePojoConverter<S, T> implements Converter<S, T> {

    final Class<T> typeParameterClass;

    public JsonToSimplePojoConverter(Class<T> typeParameterClass) {
        super();
        this.typeParameterClass = typeParameterClass;
    }

    @Override
    public T convert(S json) {
        T object = null;
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            object = mapper.readValue(((Json) json).asString(), typeParameterClass);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Problem while parsing JSON: {}", json, e);
        }
        return object;
    }
}
```

Configuration class where converter is registered:

```
@Configuration
public class ReactivePostgresConfig extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {

    @Override
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public R2dbcCustomConversions r2dbcCustomConversions() {
        List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();

//        converters.add(new JsonToAddressInfoConverter());
        converters.add(new JsonToSimplePojoConverter< Json, AddressInfo >( AddressInfo.class));
        return R2dbcCustomConversions.of(PostgresDialect.INSTANCE, converters);
    }
}
```

Error that I am getting on app initialization:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't resolve type arguments for class com.kredx.service.converters.JsonToSimplePojoConverter
    at org.springframework.data.convert.CustomConversions$StoreConversions.getRegistrationFor(CustomConversions.java:805) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.convert.CustomConversions$StoreConversions.getRegistrationsFor(CustomConversions.java:787) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.convert.CustomConversions.collectPotentialConverterRegistrations(CustomConversions.java:201) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.convert.CustomConversions.<init>(CustomConversions.java:112) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.R2dbcCustomConversions.<init>(R2dbcCustomConversions.java:60) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.R2dbcCustomConversions.of(R2dbcCustomConversions.java:88) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at com.kredx.service.config.ReactivePostgresConfig.r2dbcCustomConversions(ReactivePostgresConfig.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.kredx.service.config.ReactivePostgresConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b372d1fb.CGLIB$r2dbcCustomConversions$1(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.kredx.service.config.ReactivePostgresConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b372d1fb$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2d0d2d10.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at com.kredx.service.config.ReactivePostgresConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b372d1fb.r2dbcCustomConversions(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 114 common frames omitted
```

I am using Spring reactive + r2dbc + postgressql

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: No. I am still using individual converters for each Jsonb fields.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I also tried to create a universal converter by customizing a generic type in Converter, but it didn't work (probably because of generic type erasure, which prevented Spring from reading the type information).
After some experimentation, I found that `GenericConverter` could fulfill our requirements.
Here is the code:

```java
@WritingConverter
public static class JsonWritingConverter implements GenericConverter {
    private final Set<ConvertiblePair> convertibleTypes;

    public JsonWritingConverter(Set<Class<?>> jsonTypes) {
        this.convertibleTypes = new HashSet<>();
        for (Class<?> targetType : jsonTypes) {
            this.convertibleTypes.add(new ConvertiblePair(targetType, Json.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(convertibleTypes);
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
        return Json.of(JSON.toJSONString(source));
    }
}
```

```java
@ReadingConverter
public static class JsonReadingConverter implements GenericConverter {
    private final Set<ConvertiblePair> convertibleTypes;

    public JsonReadingConverter(Set<Class<?>> jsonTypes) {
        this.convertibleTypes = new HashSet<>();
        for (Class<?> targetType : jsonTypes) {
            this.convertibleTypes.add(new ConvertiblePair(Json.class, targetType));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(convertibleTypes);
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
            Json jsonSource = (Json) source;
            return JSON.parseObject(jsonSource.asString(), targetType.getType());
    }
}
```

It can specify multiple `Source` and `Target` type combinations explicitly through the `Class<?>` by overriding the `getConvertibleTypes` method. This is much more reliable than using generics.
Then, you can write the conversion logic for the previously specified combinations inside the `convert` method.

As for registration, it's pretty much the same as with `Converter`.

```java
@Bean
public R2dbcCustomConversions r2dbcCustomConversions(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    List<Object> converters = new ArrayList<>();
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("your.package.to.scan");
    Set<Class<?>> jsonTypes = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(StoreJson.class);
    converters.add(new JsonConverter.JsonWritingConverter(jsonTypes));
    converters.add(new JsonConverter.JsonReadingConverter(jsonTypes));
    return R2dbcCustomConversions.of(DialectResolver.getDialect(connectionFactory), converters);
}
```

I used `Reflections` to scan for custom annotations, which allowed me to obtain all the classes mapped to custom Json in one go.
Moreover, since `Converter` and `ConvertiblePair` do not have an inheritance relationship, the generic type for `List<Object>` needs to be Object.
With this configuration, you only need to annotate your classes like this:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@StoreJson
public class SessionData {
    private List<SessionDataItem> itemData;
}
```

And it will work properly.

However, as you can see, I don't know how to gracefully handle the types of JSON arrays, and can only implement them through nested objects.
I hope my answer can help you and others.